# How to call function after running ajax in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple ajax calls inside a each() function.. then do something once ALL of them are finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726046/multiple-ajax-calls-inside-a-each-function-then-do-something-once-all-of-the)

How do I execute a function after I run ajax in for loop. Example here I have this ajax running in loop,

```
for (var countDevice = 0; countDevice<32; countDevice++){
  var dataString="modbus="+(countDevice+1)+"_"+newDate+".xml";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CalculateTable",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json", 
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function( device, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     //Do something                                 
    }
  });
}
```

I want to make sure to only run this function below, only after the above for loop is finished.

```
function drawTable(){
  //Do something
}
```

Can anyone give any idea on how to make it possible? Thanks for taking the time to read and answer.

Comment: Can you change the backend code? I.e. change it to only have 1 single xhr call. This looks a bit... clunky :)

Comment: PeeHaa is correct though, the less Ajax calls you make, the better.

Comment: The *fewer* ajax calls, the better... :)

Comment: I can't seem to think any other way to make it, because the ajax call depends on 2 variables, like `countDevice` and `newDate`

Comment: You could put all the data into an object, encode it as JSON and send it to the server in one Ajax call.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for pointing those questions. Will look through them.

Comment: @FelixKling oh, I didn't occur to me to put them in object. I'll need to study more on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yoo can also try

```
$('your selector').ajaxComplete(function() {
  drawTable();
});
```

Comment: you can also try ajaxComplete method

Comment: @softsdev thank you. Your solution nearly worked, but I tweaked it to become    `$.ajax({
            complete: function(){ alert(tablehtml); }
        });` Only then it worked as I intended.

Comment: Please post that answer in your question

Answer (score 2):

if u want to running it in the linear way, u can write your code like this

```
var countDevice = 0;
(function CountDeviceLoop() {
  if (countDevice == 32) {
    // you can place draw table here or .....
    // drawTable();
    return;
  }

  var dataString="modbus="+(countDevice+1)+"_"+newDate+".xml";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CalculateTable",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json", 
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function( device, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //Do something


      //after done sth
      countDevice ++;
      CountDeviceLoop();                             
    }
  });
})();

// here
// drawTable();
```

cuz the ajax method is async, u can run your loop in this way...or if u want to use 'for loop' to run your program, you can use @MadSkunk 's code

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var countDevice = 0; countDevice<=32; countDevice++)
{
if (countDevice == 32)
{
drawTable();
}
else {
var dataString="modbus="+(countDevice+1)+"_"+newDate+".xml";
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "CalculateTable",
data: dataString,
dataType: "json",

//if received a response from the server
success: function( device, textStatus, jqXHR) {
//Do something
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: best solution just to add three more lines!

Comment: well, whoever down voted please add comments what is wrong!

Comment: Wasn't me, but... You obiously copied my post, but left in my call to isComplete() but didn't provide the code for that func!

Comment: @MadSkunk I copied your code for quick answer but i have other idea for solution!