# Wait for multiple getJSON calls to finish

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I have a loop that makes calls to an API and compiles the results into an array. How do I wait until all of the calls are finished until resuming execution? I see a bunch of answers for how to wait until one call is done, but I don't understand how to check for all of them. If I make a while loop that waits until 'obj' is the correct length, the page just stalls until the calls are done, which is not what I want. Help please?

```
function getData(id) {
    var thisI = i;
    var url = "www.whatever.com?id=" + id;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        obj[thisI]=data;
    });
}

obj = [];
for (i=0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    getData(ids[i]);
}

console.log(obj)  //this works! I see all of the elements
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=obj[0]['field'];  //TypeError: obj[0] is undefined
```

Comment: `console.log(obj)  //this works! I see all of the elements` no it doesn't... the console is tricking you most likely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple ajax calls inside a each() function.. then do something once ALL of them are finished?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726046/multiple-ajax-calls-inside-a-each-function-then-do-something-once-all-of-the)

Comment: Kevin, I think that is what is happening. If I have many calls that take more than a couple seconds, I don't see 'obj' in the console until they are all done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easy if you use jQuery's deferreds.  There is a method, `$.when`, that waits for multiple promises to complete then runs a callback.  That's what you should use here.

Don't use a global `obj` variable, you can just use the returns from the AJAX calls.

```
function getData(id) {
    var thisI = i;
    var url = "www.whatever.com?id=" + id;
    return $.getJSON(url);  // this returns a "promise"
}
```

So, instead of populating `obj`, we just return the promise.  Then in your loop, you collect all of them.

```
var AJAX = [];
for (i=0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    AJAX.push(getData(ids[i]));
}
```

Then we need to hook up the callback when all of them are done:

```
$.when.apply($, AJAX).done(function(){
    // This callback will be called with multiple arguments,
    // one for each AJAX call
    // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [data, statusText, jqXHR]

    // Let's map the arguments into an object, for ease of use
    var obj = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++){
        obj.push(arguments[i][0]);
    }

    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = obj[0]['field'];
});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Is there a way to get back to the global scope? Or does everything that is executed after have to be within this code block?

Comment: @stuppie: It's AJAX, so it's asynchronous.  You could set a global variable, but I wouldn't suggest it.  You'd have to make sure that you were accessing the global variable only after it was set, which is more work than just using the callbacks :)

Answer (score 1):

`getData` will return a promise which is a read-only version of a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  You can then execute code based on the resolution of these promises using [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)